# Add transition to MUI Chip when Delete Icon appears on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

The overall width of the chip should increase with a smooth transition when the delete Icon appears, rather than an instant increase.

Current Code structure:

```
CSS:

customChip: {
"& svg": {
  position: "relative",
  display: "none",
},
"&:hover": {
  "& svg": {
    display: "block",
    opacity: 1,
  },
},

JSX:

...
const CustomDeleteIcon = (
  <Cancel/>
);
....
<Grid item key={index} className={classes.chipContainer}>
   <Chip
      size="small"
      className={classes.customChip}
      label={
        <span style={{ whiteSpace: "initial" }}>{x.i}</span>
      }
      onDelete={(event) =>
         this.handleChipDelete(event, index)
      }
      deleteIcon={CustomDeleteIcon}
  />
</Grid>
```

[image: Current View]

Answer (score 0):

On hover, css `transistion` property can be used to get the desired output.

```
transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

we can also try using each properties separately as below,

```
transition-property: opacity;
transition-duration: 2s;
```

you can read more on this [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animatable-properties)